# sending document to Records Centre in SharePoint online using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, records-center

We have created Records Center on our SharePoint online tenancy. Now we want to send documents from other site collections to Records Center using either CSOM or JSOM. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. With CSOM use Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RecordsRepository.Records library like so:

```
var file = listItems[0].File;
ctx.Load(file, f => f.Exists);
Records.DeclareItemAsRecord(file.Context, file.ListItemAllFields);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

It will put the document into "record mode". The retention policy on the document library then transfers the document to the record center, but it needs to be set up in library settings. If everything matches (record center - site feature and list settings) you get the expected result in the record center on the next Sharepoint job run.

You can execute the job(s) yourself to skip waiting by going into Central Admin -> Monitoring ->Review job definitions-> run both: "Information management policy" and "Expiration policy".